# Doesn't sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(n) work with slicers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use a script to do something to only the rows that are not filtered when using slicers in Google Sheets. I can't get it to work.

I have tried this:

```
Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().isRowHiddenByFilter(1));
```

I get "false" even if the row is hidden by using a slicer (new feature in Google Sheets).

Anyone got it to work?

Edit: It works with regular filters, grammar, edited row number in function parameter. Replaced the phrase filter control (direct translation from Norwegian) to slicers, which is the correct english name for the feature.

Comment: I think that `0` of `isRowHiddenByFilter(0)` occurs an error. And in my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. But I thought that my method might be different from yours. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike I'll try to provide a sample later on when I've got the time for it. I'll edit the post, as I can see that there is no row 0 in a spreadsheet. The code line was used only as an example. It happens for all valid row numbers.

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. I could confirm about that. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the range filtered by the slicer cannot be retrieved, yet. By this, `isRowHiddenByFilter` cannot be used for this situation. I think that Sheets API and Spreadsheet service are growing now and are often updated. So I think that the functions for using the slicer might be added in the future. But I have to apologize that your issue cannot be resolved soon.

Comment: I created an issue in Google's issue tracker. I got the response that this feature would be requested to the engineers.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you! I upvoted your comment, but forgot to say thank you. :-)

Comment: By [the update of Google side at November 6, 2019](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#november_6_2019), [Class Slicer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/slicer) was added. Using this, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to use `isRowHiddenByFilter()` for Slicer.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

By [the update of Google side at November 6, 2019](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#november_6_2019), [Class Slicer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/slicer) was added. By this, Slicer of Spreadsheet got to be able to be managed with Google Apps Script.

In this answer, I would like to propose the method for using `isRowHiddenByFilter()` using Class Slicer.

### Flow:

Unfortunately, even when Class Slicer was added, `isRowHiddenByFilter()` cannot be directly used for the Slicer. So as a workaround, the following flow is used.

1. Retrieve the current Slicer.
2. Retrieve the range, column position and the filter criteria from the Slicer.
3. Create new basic filter using the retrieved range, column position and the filter criteria.

   - Here, the filter of Slicer is copied as the basic filter.
4. Here, `isRowHiddenByFilter()` can be used for the created basic filter.
5. Delete the basic filter.

### Usage

#### 1. Create Slicer on Spreadsheet

Here, as a test case, please manually create new Slicer on a sheet in the Spreadsheet. This sample script supposes that only one Slicer is put in the active sheet.

#### 2. IMPORTANT: Save Setting of Slicer

When **Set current filters as default** is selected (clicked), the setting of Slicer is saved. Please save the setting of the Slicer by selecting **Set current filters as default**. You can see **Set current filters as default** at the following figure.

[image]

If **Set current filters as default** is not selected, the setting of the current Slicer is not saved. Please be careful this. The official document can be seen at [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556#Setasdefault).

#### 3. Run sample script

When the function of `myFunction()` is run, the filtered values of Slicer on the active sheet can be retrieved using `isRowHiddenByFilter()`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var slicer = sheet.getSlicers()[0];
  var range = slicer.getRange();
  var filter = range
    .createFilter()
    .setColumnFilterCriteria(
      slicer.getColumnPosition(),
      slicer.getFilterCriteria()
    );
  var result = range.getValues().filter(function(_, i) {
    return !sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1);
  });
  filter.remove();
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

- In this case, when `return !sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1);` is modified to `return sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1);`, the hidden rows can be retrieved.

### References

- [isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#isRowHiddenByFilter(Integer))
- [Class Slicer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/slicer)
- [Save your slicer filtering selections](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556#Setasdefault)

Comment: Thank's a lot! I didn't see the answer until today, and I haven't tried it out. We got used to using filters without slicers, and the project will soon be phased out, so I won't check if it works. I'll sure try it if I'll get the same need in another project.

Comment: @Johan Hovda Thank you for replying. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I am trying to modify your script, but testing it as is, I get the error: "Exception: You can't create a filter in a sheet that already has a filter.
    at getSlicer(Code:6:6)".  Has the API changed or is there further setup needed to use the script?  Thanks!

Comment: @JessieinAg Thank you for your comment. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to think of the issue. Also, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

This answer adds on @Tanaike's answer.

When there are multiple slicers on the page, you cannot create new filter per slicer but instead you have to apply new filter criterias to the existing filter on the page.

```
function filterFromSlicer() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();

  slicers.forEach(slicer => {
    var range = slicer.getRange();
    var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(
      slicer.getColumnPosition(),
      slicer.getFilterCriteria()
    );
  });
  var result = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function (_, i) {
    return !sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1);
  });
  Logger.log(result);
}
```