# Get slicer value in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I recently started using slicers in Google Sheets and I would like to find a solution (probably with Apps Script) to access the current value selected in a slicer of my Spreadsheet.

Do you have any leads to solve this problem?

Comment: what do oyu mean by segment?

Comment: It seems that the name is : slicer

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: [Search](https://developers.google.com/s/results/apps-script?q=slicer)

Comment: For example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57776892/7108653

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?