# Google App Script: Get values filtered by a slicer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to get a range of values filtered by a slicer/multiple slicers using App Script? My understanding is that slicers work like a filter view which are not "hard" filters. I tried .getRange().getValues() but it returns all the data without the slicers being applied.

I have a source data in one sheet and a pivot table with slicers in another sheet.
I want the user to open the sheet with the pivot table, filter the table using the slicers and then run a script which would get the filtered range from the table.

Using the below code I see that the script gets all the data even when the slicers are applied:

```
 var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var vals = activeSheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
 var numOfResults = vals.filter(String).length;
 Logger.log(numOfResults);
```

Test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmazwEQp37Dkz41X2EjHmHEpONKqBD4g-Zhq0KuBYdU/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57776892/7108653

Comment: You can get the slicers of the document with this function https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getslicers